# Can execute a step function from a lambda but when I try to pass a value it fails saying input {}

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

So basically I've created an S3 bucket which I drop my files into. This triggers a `lambda_function(a)` which calls a step function which then triggers another `lambda_function(b)`.

I am trying to pass the file name from the bucket to `lambda_function(b)`.

So far I have:
passing the file name from S3 bucket to `lambda_function(a)`,
from here I am facing the problem where I cant pass it to the step function.

I have read numerous articles (eg https://medium.com/@tturnbull/passing-data-between-lambdas-with-aws-step-functions-6f8d45f717c3) but I just cant seem to get it working...

so My `lambda_function(a)` looks like so:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const stepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions({
region: 'us-west-2'
});

let index = function index(event, context, callback) {
      
const fileName = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
const params = {
    stateMachineArn: 'MY-STATE-MACHINE-NO',
    name: fileName
};

stepFunctions.startExecution(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'There was an error'
        })
    };
    callback(null, response);
    } else {
    console.log(data);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Step function worked'
        }),
    };
    callback(null, response);
    }
});
};

module.exports.init = (event, context, callback) => {
};
exports.handler = index;
```

This all works fine. My step function looks like so:

```
  {
  "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using a Pass state",
  "StartAt": "HelloWorld",
  "States": {
    "HelloWorld": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "MY-ARN-NUMBER",
      "InputPath": "$.title",
      "ResultPath": "$.title",
      "OutputPath": "$.title",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I know this is working because if I start an execution on the step function with

```
{
    "title":"131231231.xml"
}
```

this filename stored in 'title' gets passed to `lambda_function(b)` as 'event'

So the problem I am left with is trying to get it from lambda_function(a) to the step function.

I know it has to be sent as a JSON so if you refer back to my function I have edited it to include:

```
 const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: 'Step function worked',
    title :"131231231.xml"
    }),
    title :"131231231.xml"
};
callback(null, response);
}
```

But this fails on the step function with:

```
    {
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'HelloWorld' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.title' : No results for path: $['title']"
}
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @rajesh for replying I was able to determine that

console.log('RESPONSE: ' + response);

prints RESPONSE: [object Object]

SO I changed the response to be

```
{
  var response = JSON.stringify({"title":"131231231.xml"});
};
console.log('RESPONSE: ' + response);
callback(null, response);
```

In the logs this returns...

```
RESPONSE: {"title":"131231231.xml"}
```

So technically this should be right?..wrong...If I check the step function it fails with the output error message of

```
    {
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'HelloWorld' (entered at the event id #2). Invalid path '$.title' : No results for path: $['title']"
}
```

and If I check the input tab in the execution details in the step function the input shows empty as... `{}`

So why is the input not capturing the 'title' JSON...any ideas?

Comment: Try to print the JSON String before the invocation to StepFunction and compare that with the JSON string that works when invoking the StepFunction directly

Comment: Thank you for your message I have tried what you suggested and think I have got a little further with it and have been able to diagnose what is causing the issue...Please have a look at my UPDATE in my OP. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your input in the `name` field of `params`. However, you need to pass your input through the `input` field of params (which is empty in your case, hence the error). Try:

```
const params = {
    stateMachineArn: 'MY-STATE-MACHINE-NO',
    input: "{\"title\" : \"" + fileName + "\"}"
};
```

See the [sdk's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#startExecution-property) for more info:

```
var params = {
  stateMachineArn: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  input: 'STRING_VALUE',
  name: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
stepfunctions.startExecution(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

> input — (String)
>   The string that contains the JSON input data for the execution, for example:
>   "input": "{\"first_name\" : \"test\"}"