# AWS Lambda: Input values needs to be concatenated with error message

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda

The query returns the expected result, the request in this forum is regarding the customized error message.  Incase of failure the exception needs to stored along with the input values.

This is my first lambda code, please let me know any additional details.

**Input**

```
{"EventID":"1246", "DataflowID": "011010"}
```

**Lambda Code** (Nodejs), this was nodejs but suggestion in python are also appreciated.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mydocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

    var params = {
        TableName: 'TransactionLog',
        KeyConditionExpression : 'EventID = :EventID and Status = :Status',
        FilterExpression : 'EventID in (:EventID) and Status in (:Status)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {":EventID": event.WorkflowDetail.EventID,":Status": "progress"},
        ProjectionExpression: "EventID,DataflowID,Status"
      };
    
      
      mydocumentClient.scan(params, function (err, data){
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
          callback(null, data);
        }
    }
    )

}
```

**Actual Example Error Message:** Resource not found.

**Expected Error Message:** Resource not found  "EventID":"1246", "DataflowID": "011010"

I tried using different options but no luck. please advise.

```
console.log(element.Title.S + " (" + element.Subtitle.S + ")");
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare all the required events inside the parmas. I'm not sure this is the best solution but it meets my requirement. Thanks!

```
 var params = {
       ...,
       ....,
        Input: "{\"column1\" : \"" + 'type' + "\",  \"column2\" : \"" + 'time' +\"}"
      };

console.log(params.Input, err);
```

useful thread: [Can execute a step function from a lambda but when I try to pass a value it fails saying input {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769546/can-execute-a-step-function-from-a-lambda-but-when-i-try-to-pass-a-value-it-fail)